# Tensorflow: How to find diagonal element of rank 4 tensor into a rank 3 tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensor

Suppose I have a rank four tensor: `T_{i,j,p,q},` and I want to find the diagonal element of first two dimensions to form a new tensor: `T_{i,i,p,q}` into `T_{i,p,q}`. How should I do it in tensorflow?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with some sample tensors (input and output) please?

Comment: suppose I create a tensor T = tf.random_normal(shape = [4,4,6,7], dtype = tf.float32), and I want to find the diagonal element of first two dimensions to form a new tensor of shape=[4,6,7].

Comment: What does the diagonal of a non-square tensor look like? Again, please provide some sample with numbers etc

Comment: @coldspeed Hi, the tensor is square in the first two dimensions. In numpy, I could call np.diag(T, axis=[0,1]) but in tensorflow the corresponding function doesn’t have axis option.